# Matrix power and its product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $P$ are $n \times n$ matrix, when does $(P^{-1}AP)^n=P^{-1}A^nP$?

And how do I prove that the equation is true given the condition?

Comment: Mathematical induction.

Comment: @ Git Gud and One And All:  I'll *always* upvote Mathematical Induction!  +1 for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(P^{-1}AP)(P^{-1}AP)=(P^{-1}A)(PP^{-1})AP$

Comment: As for the proof, try induction.

Comment: I did, thank you so much!